# How would a Jupiter sized planet impact humanity?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, low-fantasy

So while worldbuilding I was pondering the effects of such a large planet on humans and their development alongside magic, technology, society, etc. So the planet is like Earth in water/land ratio, but (as said in the title) the size of Jupiter. This of course without the gravity and geothermal stuff.

I'm still working and tweaking the magic system, but here it is. Magic is not limited as *spells* or anything, only focus and energy. Magic, in this sense, is a "natural" power that flows everywhere and connects everything. Mages in this world can manipulate the energy via absorbing and expelling magic energy through an organ. Magic is nervous system triggered (kindof) and needs the user to focus and mentally describe what they want magic to do. The effects of magic are observable, predictable, and repeatable.

The setting is the generic medieval fantasy, however, the 5 races are replaced with different human races (not just 5 of course). "Gods" in this world are just sufficiently magically advanced humans and not as powerful as generic gods (still mortal). There are monsters, another factor, but they're more like animals, most aren't as intelligent as humans.

So, how would a Jupiter sized planet impact humanity?

Comment: Sorry if this looks rushed, I was multitasking and also hurried.

Comment: Five times more races, but 120 times more surface area. My guess is that some races never actually find each other until they get to the spaceflight era.

Comment: I honestly cannot understand what you are asking. Do you just want to know how humans would have developed differently if we had 5x the land area to explore? That's too broad to ever answer... the answers are myriad.

Comment: My question is probably too broad, my bad :P But to tighten my question I basically wanted ideas on how humans would react to more resources and land, and how they would evolve. For example, since there is more land and ample resources, there would be no wars for those right? My question is still probably too broad, sorry. I'm finding it hard to describe what im trying to ask.

Comment: Given 4.5 billion years, would the whole planet even be populated by complex life? Would abiogenesis occur multiple times, leading to multiple different biochemical hemispheres? Evolution on such a world would be very, *very* interesting.

Comment: "what is the effect of X on society/humanity?" is always too broad.

Comment: How do humans react to more resources? As they always do! "Resources exist to be consumed, and consumed they will be, if not by this generation then by some future. What right has this forgotten future to our birthright? Let us eat and drink our fill!" -- fictional quote from Nwabudike Morgan from fictional text *The Ethics of Greed* I find it pretty much dead on. There was ample empty space on Earth until the 20th century. Wars happened continuously anyway throughout our history. People want a specific land, even if other land is available.